# How to highlight ExpandableListView group on group expansion via xml?

Tags: android, xml, expandablelistview

I want highlight group view of `ExpandableListView` when it opened. I realize that I need to make selector. Can I use group selector in XML-layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ExpandableListView has a property called android:listSelector that you can pass a selector, however I couldn't find a state that could be used if the Group is expanded or not. Using android:state_pressed seemed to work when the groupItem is touched, but after releasing it, it's state went back, and the highlight disappeared.

What I ended up doing is checking the isExpanded value in the ExpandableListView Adapters getGroupView function, and set the returned Views background based on that value:

```
@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertView == null){
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate.....;
    }
    if(isExpanded){
       convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.listgroup_background_active);
    }else{
        convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.listgroup_background);
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

Hope this helps